# Text string split\cut

Tags: sql, sql-server

|
I have many strings that need to be cut\split according to one basic rule - split\ cut between the 1st ";" to the 2nd ";" and than paste it under new column.

for examples one of my rows data is:

```
 Y 4+2 A SAMPLES; Res 50Xp3 TP; HRI ; Bin n/a; Skew: RS; Source: Y805 [100] (Qty 100);
```

from this row I should retrieve: "Res 50Xp3 TP"

I think I tried all split option without success I also tried to use PATINDEX\CHARINDEX and it didn't help.

Thanks,

Comment: hi, you can help me to modify this solution to the end of my data?
in this example I wish to see the last ";" + the one before it (all between them). Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done things like this in my scripts using combination of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRINGs

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200) = 'Y 4+2 A SAMPLES; Res 50Xp3 TP; HRI ; Bin n/a; Skew: RS; Source: Y805 [100] (Qty 100)'
DECLARE @char VARCHAR(1) = ';'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(
            LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX(@char, @str)+1, LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@char, @str))),
            0,
            CHARINDEX(@char, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX(@char, @str)+1, LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@char, @str))))
            )
```

output

```
Res 50Xp3 TP
```

in reference to the comments

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(
            LTRIM(SUBSTRING(v.description,CHARINDEX(';', v.description)+1, LEN(v.description)-CHARINDEX(';', v.description))),
            0,
            CHARINDEX(';', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(v.description,CHARINDEX(';', v.description)+1, LEN(v.description)-CHARINDEX(';', v.description))))
            ) AS 'YourText'
FROM vw_public_vpo AS v
```

Comment: Hi, my data stored at "vw_public_vpo.description" column and I need this option to run on all rows, how can I update 
"DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200) = 'Y 4+2 A SAMPLES; Res 50Xp3 TP; HRI ; Bin n/a; Skew: RS; Source" to use my column data and not specific text.

Comment: replace @str with w_public_vpo.description in your query. Also replace char variable with ';' in your query though since that is static you can keep the declare.

Comment: can you please show me how it should looks like from the Declare? because after im changing it it cannot be execute.. I probably miss something here. Thanks again!

Comment: can you update your question with a simple query so we know the table and schema, then I can just modify that.

Comment: I just saw that I miss one character in my query, It works perfect now!! Thanks a lot!! I did not change the "char variable with ';', it is important? I not really understood what dose it means.

Answer (score 2):

One options is using a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Y 4+2 A SAMPLES; Res 50Xp3 TP; HRI ; Bin n/a; Skew: RS; Source: Y805 [100] (Qty 100);')

Select ID
      ,NewValue = ltrim(rtrim(convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(SomeCol,';','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')))
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewValue
1   Res 50Xp3 TP
```

Comment: I like it!  I learn new stuff every day on SO from people like you John!

Comment: @MatthewWeir Truly one of the best parts of SO.   :)